# is GPIO export necessary?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, beagleboard, gpio

I'm writing some code for interacting with GPIO via writing values to the `/sys/class/gpioX/value` file.

My question is, I see some references to an `export` file at and writing
the requested pin to the export file.

I was under the impression that the GPIO bus(?) watched for changes to all the gpioX value files. Is this not correct? Do I need to tell the system to watch for changes by including the value in the export file? What if I want to watch for changes on multiple GPIO pins? Do I have to loop through the pins I want to watch? That seems inefficient.

Comment: There's a way to [use interrupts instead of polling](http://raspberrywebserver.com/gpio/using-interrupt-driven-gpio.html), maybe this will give you direction. If you search google for `raspberry pi gpio interrupts` you may find more of them articles.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [libsoc](https://github.com/jackmitch/libsoc). According to its description, it provides various methods to watch for GPIO changes:

> - Blocking GPIO Interrupts with timeout
> - Non-blocking GPIO Interrupts with callback mechanism (pthread based)

This library is already a part of [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) Embedded Linux Distribution.